# Unable to open subdirectory laravel installation

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

In my `/public_html/` I have installed an WordPress site. Now I have installed an laravel application inside `/public_html/app/`.

Then in `/public_html/app/.htaccess` I have added:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In `/public_html/app/public/.htaccess` I have added:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteBase /app/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I trying to open `https://example.com/app/` I've got error 404. When I try to open directly `https://example.com/app/public` I've got half working site because it is searching for the css/images in `https://example.com/`.

What is need to be changed in the `htaccess`s in order to work.

The goal is to have a button on the main WP site and when I click it to load the laravel site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteBase /app/
> ```

You need to *remove* the `RewriteBase` directive. This ends up rewriting the request to `/app/index.php`, when it should be `/app/public/index.php`. The default is to rewrite to the current directory (the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file), so the `RewriteBase` directive is not required here.

(Or, you could set this "correctly" to `RewriteBase /app/public` - but that is not necessary and would then hardcode this installation to the `/app` directory.)

> I've got half working site because it is searching for the css/images in `https://example.com/`

It depends on where your images are. If images are located at `/app/public/assets/images/myimage.jpg` then you should be referencing your images using a root-relative URL (starting with a slash), excluding the `public` directory, eg. `href="/app/assets/images/myimage.jpg"`.

---

**UPDATE:**

> is this means that I now have to manually edit all images, links, buttons, etc on the site in order to add `/app/...` in front of the assets?

Ordinarily, yes. In the same way you have presumably added `/app/` before all your internal links to your pages. (?)

> Logo for example - `<img src="/assets/main/img/logo.png">`

However, since you are using a root-relative URL and your Laravel assets are in a known location, then you could workaround this by implementing a rewrite in the root (WordPress) `.htaccess` file to rewrite your Laravel assets to the correct location (presumably `/app/public/...`).

However, this does mean that you cannot then have an `/assets` subdirectory in the root (without implementing additional filesystem checks), nor have a WordPress URL that starts `/assets`, since it will conflict and won't be accessible.

For example, at the top of the `/.htaccess` file, *before* any other WordPress directives you could do something like the following:

```
# Rewrite Laravel assets to the correct location
RewriteRule ^assets/.+ app/public/$0 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

Where `$0` is a backreference that contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Now, any request for `/assets/<something>` will be internally rewritten to `/app/public/assets/<something>`. `/assets/` itself won't be rewritten.

Comment: thanks. `..then you should be referencing your images using a root-relative URL...` is this means that I now have to manually edit all images, links, buttons, etc on the site in order to add `/app/...` in front of the assets?

Comment: @JasonWung How are you currently referencing your assets?

Comment: Logo for example - `<img src="/assets/main/img/logo.png">`

Comment: @JasonWung Well, yes, ordinarily you would need to prefix these URLs with `/app`. However, since you are consistently using a root-relative URL currently, you can workaround this by implementing an additional rewrite in the root (WordPress) `.htaccess` file. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This solution works perfectly! Thank you very much for you help.